# Google ajax crawling not working with fetch as google

Tags: ajax, orchardcms, web-crawler, google-search-console

I am trying to test with "fetch as google" an orchard website which has ajax content . Shouldn't google replace http://cmbbeta.azurewebsites.net/#! with http://cmbbeta.azurewebsites.net/?_escaped_fragment_ (both links work). When i hit my beta website with fetch as google, the preview shows me that the page is loading the ajax content,and not the static one.

Am i missing something?

Comment: When I try the links you provided in my browser, they both return the same content (with ajax), so something looks wrong with your setup. How did you implement the static version?

Comment: I just tried the links again. The first link is returns content thru ajax. Second one looks similiar but is actually a snapshot, the content is rendered from the server. You can check the page out with the developer tools to see that no additional network activity is generated. Thanks for your help

Comment: When you say that "the preview shows me that the page is loading the ajax content", are you talking about what you see when you click the "Success" link in the "Fetch Status" column? Or are you talking about the preview that appears when you mouse over the link?

Comment: I looked now on the code in the Success link and feel very stupid now :|. So the preview picture is taking a snapshot without the actual link uglification? This is my first time that i use webmaster tools for this purpose so i didn't realize that i was looking into the wrong place

Comment: Yes, the preview always seem to show the dynamic website. The important thing to look at is what you see under Fetch Status.

Comment: Can you post the comment as an anwser so that i can accept your answer

Comment: Added it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preview that appears when you put your mouse over the link always seem to show the dynamic website. The important thing to look at is the fetch result that you can access by clicking the "Success" link in the "Fetch Status" column.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not affecting your site, but the Fetch as Google feature doesn't work for AJAX urls that are specified with the `<meta>` tag.  See [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/webmasters/crawling-indexing--ranking/bZgWCJTnl08%5B1-25-false%5D).